# dropdown list in JSP from database

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, foreach, jstl

I'm new to Spring, I fear this question may be duplicate, as there are numerous ways to do get resource from database to drop-down which I don't understand, so I'm asking if anyone can help me by fixing my code or with their own code which matches with mine as it'll be easy for me to learn.

My POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp69")
public class Emp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String designation;

....Constructor with name & designation field...

......getters method and setters method.....
```

My Repository

```
public interface EmpRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
@Modifying
@Query(
        value = "select designation from employee",
        nativeQuery = true
)
List<String> designation();

}
```

My Data Access Object

```
@Service
public class EmployeeDao {
    @Autowired
    private EmpRepository repo;

    @Transactional
    public List<String> desig() {
        return repo.designation();
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/empform")
    public String showform(Model m) {
        List<String> designation= dao.designation();
        m.addAttribute("designation", designation);
        return "empform";
    }
}
```

My JSP page

```
<select>
    <c:forEach var="dd" items="${designation}">
        <option><c:set var="dd.designation">${dd.designation }</c:set></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

seems everything fine to me but when I execute, it gives

`Property [designation] not found on type [java.lang.String]`

error.

And on STS console

`javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property [designation] not found on type [java.lang.String]`

Comment: Just use `<option><c:set var="d" value="${dd}" /></option>` since you have object of `List<String>`.

Comment: Also, you're using JPA, so you should favor JPQL queries over SQL (native) queries.  The equivalent JPQL query would be `select e.designation from Emp e`. I also trongly advise to make your code readable by using actual, complete words: Employee instead of Emp, findDesignations() instead of desig(), etc.

Comment: Nothing shows on drop-down table has 2 more entity id and name @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: @java-user, you are not querying for those fields in `EmpRepository` and you are passing the `List<String>` to the frontend instead of `List<Emp>`.

Comment: Ya I tried that too but it leads to error which says `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.` on console @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: @java-user, can you add the Employee POJO class.

Comment: I did as you said but it still gives an error and also I edited what you asked. @JBNizet

Comment: have a look I've added pojo class @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: @java-user, then there will be no multiple designations, what are you trying to show in the frontend with `Select`?

Comment: in database there are two designations with name & id respectively, that I've previously saved, so I am trying to retrieve that designation to drop-down @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: @java-user, Really not getting what you are trying to achieve. You can edit the question like I wanted the code to behave like this, for that I have done these codes, and getting these issues.

Comment: Got it you missed just this part `<c:out value="${d }"/>` you were right. Thank you for lending me your precious time. As I've started Spring boot there will be a lot questions... Please look out for me, if you wish @NaveenKumarHS

Comment: This is not Spring Boot related .. This is essentially just basic JSP/EL. It's advisable to take a step back from a big framework and individually learn each of its aspects first, such as JSP and then EL and then JSTL and then Servlet and then Spring MVC etc. This way the inner workings of the big framework sitting on top of them will become much more clear.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC for your advice, it won't repeat again. _I've so much to learn_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller, Service & Repository part are correct but it seems like you haven't studied **JSP** well. I'll suggest you to take a step back from a big framework and individually learn each of its aspects first like **JSP**, **JSTL**, etc. Following this path will lead you to understanding of big frameworks and everything will be more clear.

Anyhow here's your answer..

```
<select>
    <c:forEach var="dd" items="${designation}">
        <option><c:set var="d" value="${dd}" /><c:out value="${d }"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

just replace this part in your code..

Hope it helps